# ¿Cómo agrego bordes redondeados a un video?

Tags: flutter, dart

Me gustaría agregar bordes redondeados a mi video, al igual que se hace con las fotos. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?
Utilizo la librería [video player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) para mostrar el video

Intenté lo siguiente:

```
AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: videoController!.value.aspectRatio,
    child:Container(
        decoration:BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
        ),
        child: FittedBox(
            fit:BoxFit.cover,
            child: VideoPlayer(videoController!)
        ),
    ),
)
```

Pero, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> FlutterError (TextureBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

Para solucionarlo intenté ponerle mediadas al `Container`

```
 height: 300,
 width: 300,
```

Pero, aún así el problema persiste. Intenté envolver también el `AspectRatio` en un `SizedBox` y tampoco funcionó.

Si quito el `FittedBox` el error se va así que supongo vendrá de ahí.

Answer (score 1):

el FittedBox básicamente nos ayuda a rellenar los contenedores de manera que la calidad no se vea afectada, esta propiedad también la puedes encontrar dentro de las mismas clases `Image` en su propiedad `fit`.
Ahora, en vez de declarar el borderRadius dentro del decorations de los contenedores, intenta encapsular tu FittedBox dentro de un ClipRrect, se veria algo asi:

```
    AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: videoController!.value.aspectRatio,
    child:Container(
         height: 300,
         width: 300,
         child:ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10) 
            FittedBox(
            fit:BoxFit.cover,
            child: VideoPlayer(videoController!)
        ),
      ),
    ),
)
```

Espero esto te funcione!.

Comment: Persiste el mismo error que en la publicación